# Change JSON string using RegEx

Tags: regex, json

I would like to do a global replace on a string like this:

```
var d = "{\"AlertDate\": \"\/Date(1277334000000+0100)\/\",\"Progress\": 1,\"ReviewPeriod\": 12}";
```

and replace all the /Date(1234656000000+0100)/ fields with the following:

```
"{\"AlertDate\": \"new Date(1234656000000+0100)",\"Progress\": 1,\"ReviewPeriod\": 12}";
```

How could I do this with a regular expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
d.replace(/\/(Date\(\d{13}\+\d{4}\))\//, "New $1");
```